# how to fix a manim issue with : no file .svg in image directory

Tags: tikz, manim

Hello I can't play any tikzpicture with manim. I run on mac. I've already include packages in tex_template.tex. Do I need to add them in ctex_template.tex aswell ?
I've also modified the tex_file_writing.py including the folowing at line 88 :

`--libgs = '/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/lib/libgs.dylib'`

But as I run a code I got this error message :

*OSError: No file matching /Users/--name--/ManimInstall/manim_3fev/manimlib/files/Tex/51ea75cce814cb1c.svg in image directory*

Could you help me ? I will be so gratful !

Answer (score 1):

Copy this to your tex_template.tex file, it is not need use ctex.
The line:
`--libgs = '/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/lib/libgs.dylib'`
it has to go under the variable [result](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/48f2a1ec3c86f3ad26b6b1292b6917149005cbab/manimlib/utils/tex_file_writing.py#L87), in the method `dvi_to_svg`.

```latex
\documentclass[preview,dvisvgm]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,trees}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{folding}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{plothandlers}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{topaths}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = * }
%\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\linespread{1}

\begin{document}

YourTextHere

\end{document}
```

If this doesn't work, try removing the line `--libgs = '/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/lib/libgs.dylib'` or/and removing the `dvisvgm` in the tex_template file.

Comment: It works ! I modified the tex_template.tex file : "dvisvgm" was missing  in documentclass options. 
I also removed  this line --libgs = '/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/lib/libgs.dylib' in tex_file_writing.py
Many thanks for this help !!

Comment: Thanks to you, thank you very much for your donation, it is appreciated.

Comment: It should also work without class option `dvisvgm`. Just remove the spaces before and after the equal sign of option `libgs`, so that it looks like this: `--libgs=/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/lib/libgs.dylib`. The spaces lead to a command-line error.

Comment: I've done everything recommended here, but it keeps telling me: Exception: Latex error converting to dvi.

Comment: Then you don't have full latex installed, check what package are you missing. Or maybe you are making a mistake in your LaTeX code.